# Use Internet connection sharing and proxy server with window 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy

Currently my computer is connected with ethernet cable from router.

I want to make proxy server so that i should know how much data is used by which computer.

I have two LAN cards on computer.

I want to conncet cable from modem directly to my server and then from server to router.

Is this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Take a look at [Kerio WinRoute Firewall](http://www.kerio.com/firewall).